# Where is node-redis v4 documentation/migration guide?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

`node-redis` refactored its API in v4 to support Promises. For some reason, they also decided to change the signature of most commands, which now don't obey any apparent logic. For example, this is the signature of ZADD:

```
.zAdd('key', { score: 1, value: 'value' })
```

And this one of ZRANGE:

```
.zRange(key, min, max, { BY: "SCORE", LIMIT: { offset , count } })
```

In ZINTERSTORE they even omit one parameter from the native Redis command.

My purpose is not to rant about the inconsistency in the new API, just to ask where is the migration guide, since the link in their page is broken. Or, should we just look into the source code (as I did)?

Comment: Here's the migration guide https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/v4.0.0-rc.0/docs/v3-to-v4.md however it doesn't seem to be complete. You can also check this GitHub thread for changes not mentioned there: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1765

Comment: Which parameter is missing in `ZINTERSTORE`? Regarding the command types - you can find them [here](https://redis.js.org/documentation/client/)

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman `ZINTERSTORE` receives the number of keys as a second parameter. I just don't know if there is much sense in adding a layer of abstraction this thin over the original commands. Thanks for the docs!

Comment: @Federico

1. type checking and code completion
2. take a look at [GEOSEARCH](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch), [FT.SEARCH](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Commands/#ftsearch), and [HGETALL](https://redis.io/commands/HGETALL)
3. you can always use `.sendCommand` directly.

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman I believe code completion can also be achieved with the previous commands, it's just a matter of restricting the possible strings. In any case, I'm not against changing the API, the problem is that the methods are not consistent in the way in which they are named (uppercase/lowercase, using the same name as in the native redis command or using a different name, etc.). Adding to that, as you can see from the link above in Zuku's comment , the documentation is scarce and the community wasn't happy with the way breaking changes were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get scores, there's a new method for that

```
let rawData = await redis.zRangeWithScores(
    key,
    '+inf', // this means infinity
    '-inf',
    {
      BY: 'SCORE',
      REV: true
    }
  );
```

There are some useful questions and answers on [this issues thread for node-redis](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1705)

Mainly, that you need to reverse the min/max when calling the `REV: true` option, and that you use `+inf` instead of 0 and '-inf' instead of -1